# Android annotations: Different layout for portrait and landscape

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I am using AA and would like to specify two different xml layout files for portrait and landscape orientations.

In my java class, marked as EActivity a method annotated with @Click is provided to respond to click event.

Everything is working fine in portrait mode. But when the phone is rotated, the layout changes and buttons are not responding anymore.

My guess is that the layout provided after @EActivity annotation is the portrait layout.

How can I provide both portrait and landscape layouts ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I 'listen' to orientation changes using two different layout files one, for portrait which is named layout/contact.xml and the other, for landscape which is named layout-land/contact.xml. Android does the rest and uses the correct layout according to phone orientation.

To register listener for click events, I use Android Annotations:

**contact.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <!-- Some elements -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**header_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuHome"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
        android:paddingTop="22dp"
        android:paddingBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- Other buttons -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**contact.java**

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_contact)
public class ContactActivity extends TopLevelActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle() {
        return "Nous contacter";
    }
}
```

** TopLevelActivity.java **

```
@EActivity
public abstract class TopLevelActivity extends Activity implements ITopLevelActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Click
    public void menuHome () {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity_.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you listening to the orientation changes and when are you registering the views for click listening? Add this code so we can better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your java file

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_h);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_v);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Also, add the following to your activity in the Manifest:
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: I have updated my question, and tried what you suggested of course. Thanks for your answer, I added your piece of code in contact.java but the method is not called (I put a breakpoint and it was never triggered).

Comment: you'll have to add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to your activity on the manifest, if don't do that then this method is not called, see  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it solved my problem. Put it in an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Comment: Accept @sasikumar answer as it has the main part of the answer, I edited the answer to include the missing manifest part, it should appear after the review process is complete :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create different layout configurations for portrait or landscape orientation preserving **single resource file name** that will be **picked up automatically** by the system you can use configuration qualifiers.

Configuration qualifiers used to determine which resource should be used. We have multiple qualifiers in Android system: ["Table 2. Configuration qualifier names."](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

Here are sample screenshots to explain how you pick desired configuration qualifiers.

1) First, you enter resource name and select a qualifier from "Available qualifiers" list;

[image: Selecting desired configuration qualifiers]

2) Press **[>>]** button to move selected qualifier to the list of "Chosen qualifiers";
3) Now you have qualifier selected and can specify value for each individual qualifier.

*Note: you cannot select one type of qualifier only once per file. E.g. one size qualifier, one density qualifier, etc.*

[image: Selected orientation qualifier]

In "Project View" tab under `app/src/main/res` you can see next structure:

1) In "Android view" mode:

[image: Project View tab, Android presentation mode]

2) In "Project Files" mode

[image: Project View tab, Project Files presentation mode]

### EXTREMELY IMPORTANT

You should provide default version of resource file under default folders like `layout`, `drawable`, `values` etc., if you have resource files that depend on configuration qualifiers. If configuration qualifiers are not met, meaning device running your application does not qualify to use given resources, and your application does not have default resource file your application will crash with

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b001c
```